# Store images in file or media entity?

Tags: 8, media

When I start a Drupal project, should I use the Media module for image files?

I hope I can upgrade to Drupal 8.3, where parts of the Media module are in core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with Media suite simply because I believe files should be treated like full entities as nodes are. It grants you more options and flexibility in media management and reuse instead of the standard upload field.